# Foreign keys and cluster

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

I have a schema that uses InnoDB table type and foreign keys.
I am planning to use mysql Cluster and I just want to make sure that I can use "InnoDB" table type and foreign key constraints will be still valid.

**Update:**

As per the documentation:

> It is possible to create tables using
>   other storage engines (such as MyISAM
>   or InnoDB) on a MySQL server being
>   used with a MySQL Cluster, but these
>   non-NDB tables do not participate in
>   clustering; each such table is
>   strictly local to the individual MySQL
>   server instance on which it is
>   created.

Does it mean that if I create an InnoDB table, I can have foreign key constraint? I understand those tables will not participate in clustering.

Comment: What is your question? as far as I know there are no foreign keys in InnoDB.

Comment: Actually there are foreign keys in InnoDB :)

Comment: InnoDB **has** full referential integrity. It's MyISAM which is defficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they all use [`NDBCLUSTER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/faqs-mysql-cluster.html#qandaitem-B-10-1-19) as a storage engine, and [foreign key constraints are not available](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-limitations-unsupported.html) **before 5.6/  MySQL Cluster NDB 7.3**. Starting with [MySQL Cluster NDB 7.3 foreign keys are possible](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-cluster-limitations-resolved.html).

Tables that do not participate in clustering can be InnoDB (or any other ), but are local to the server only (i.e. the other servers are not aware of that table), so the table can only be queried on one of the nodes (which kind of defeats the advantages of clustering).

All features of the engine are then of course available, so indeed, the InnoDB table can have foreign key constraints, but the same rules apply with InnoDB<>NDB as InnoDB<>MyISAM: MySQL won't complain if you mention a column located in an NDB/MyISAM table in an InnoDB table definition, but won't enforce the integrity either.

Comment: Foreign key constraints appear to be supported as of [MySQL 5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-cluster-limitations-unsupported.html).

Comment: @EJP: you are indeed right, [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-cluster-limitations-resolved.html) is even more explicit.

Comment: @EJP: updated the answer accordingly, thank you for pointing this out ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to programmatically enforce foreign keys in NDB (or any mysql storage engine which does not natively support them):
http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-enforcing-foreign-keys.html

Or if you can wait for MySQL Cluster 7.3 :
https://blogs.oracle.com/MySQL/entry/mysql_cluster_7_3_labs

Answer (score 0):

MySQL cluster does not support foreign keys as imposing foreign key constraint may reduce the performance of cluster .You can design your database in such a fashion that operations on database would keep the required checks.